# Find RegEx for Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am used to write regular expression and do understand it however I tried hard to generate regex for below pattern, but finally need help from you guys.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ...
...
...
BEGIN

  DECLARE ...
  DECLARE ...
...
END
```

What I am looking for is to extract 3 groups using Java RegEx:

1st section is from CREATE FUNCITON to BEGIN,

2nd is statements starting with DECLARE and

3rd one is rest everything after DECLARE statements to END.

(See below)

```
---------------------
CREATE FUNCTION ...
...
...
BEGIN
---------------------
  DECLARE ...
  DECLARE ...
---------------------
...
END
---------------------
```

Comment: Unless you control the source you are trying to parse, regexps are not the best tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: @Biffen, see 1st comment. parsing source code is a task beyond the capabilities of regex

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Why can't I use Group of RegEx to extract this ? Can you please elaborate your comment a bit ?

Comment: You can, but it is not the best tool.

Comment: @Pratik. think of cases where a function is called "FUNCTION" or cases where a variable is initialized with "BEGIN" string, etc

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I can assure that we can avoid such corner cases, there won't be any such case.

Comment: @Pratik, you should take a look into language parsers. the most popular one is [ANTLR](https://www.antlr.org/), but there are [lots of others](https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-java/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the text always comes in a very regular fashion, regex is not a suitable for parsing source code like this. You should write/use a parser instead.

Assuming:

- There will be no DECLARE statements between CREATE FUNCTION and BEGIN
- There will not be any other statements in between the DECLARE statements
- There will always be at least one DECLARE statement

You can use a regex like this:

```
([\s\S]+?)((?:\s+DECLARE.+)+)([\s\S]+)
```

Note that this can cause catastrophic backtracking if there are no DECLARE statements. If the input could have no DECLARE statements, you could just match the `(?:\s+DECLARE.+)+` part, and get the other two groups with substring:

```
String input = "CREATE FUNCTION ...\n" +
        "...\n" +
        "...\n" +
        "BEGIN\n" +
        "\n" +
        "  DECLARE ...\n" +
        "  DECLARE ...\n" +
        "...\n" +
        "END";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?:\\s+DECLARE.+)+").matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    String firstPart = input.substring(0, m.start());
    String secondPart = m.group();
    String thirdPart = input.substring(m.end());
    System.out.println(thirdPart);
}
```

Comment: @Sweepwe, Now a days its a trend to downvote questions on stackoverflow very easily, even if you try to explain it very decently. I did spend so many ours behind this but may be I was not very good with backreferencing and lookahead operators. But I really appreciate your answer and the efforts you put in for me. Thank you very much again :)